# PHP associative array keys not being set

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative

In this snippet $opt is an xpath node created from this tag:

```
<option name="all">1</option>

//...
$this->permissions = array();
$key = $opt['name'];
$value = $opt[0];
echo $key . "=" . $value;
$this->permissions[$key] = $value;
echo $this->permissions['all'];
//...
```

From these echo statements I get the following return:

```
all=1
```

Which is expected from the first echo, but the second prints nothing.

When I do:
    echo array_keys($this->permissions);

I get:
    Array

When I do:
    var_dump($this->permissions);

I get:
    array(0) { }

When I do:
    print_r($this->permissions);
or:
    print_r(array_keys($this->permissions));

I get:
    Array ( )

Any ideas, anyone? why are the keys coming back as arrays? What am I missing here...

Comment: Do a `print_r($this->permissions);` and post back the result.

Comment: The result of array_keys is an Array. You're surprised? Read the documentation.

Comment: [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) --> Return Values: Returns an **array** of all the keys in input. **READ THE DOCS PLEASE**

Comment: Edited with the results of print_r and var_dump.

Comment: Thanks, yes I read the documentation. The real issue here is that when I echo $this->permissions['all'] I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var_dump($opt);
```

and post back the results

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(3) "all" } }

Comment: something is wrong with $opt because I can't see the "1" value here. you should have something like "[0] int(1) 1" in this var dump. where in your code is this var_dump ?

Comment: I noticed that also, but in the echo statement it is coming back as expected "all=1" I added another node to the xml file with 'some' as the name and 2 in the tag, and I get all=1some=2 as expected also. I just switched the code over to...
    $key = $opt['name'];
    $value = $opt['value'];
    echo $key . "=" . $value;
    $this->permissions[$key] = $value;
    echo $this->permissions['all'];
    echo $this->permissions['some'];
and the xml nodes are now <option name="all" value="1" /> etc, just to see if opt was acting strangely. Defining $key and $value work fine.

Comment: I tried it with the var_dump immediately after defining $opt, and after I tried to assign the array value, both had the same results.

Comment: The new var_dump for that arrangement is: object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(3) "all" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: $string = <<<XML
 <option name="all"></option>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml); gives the same result as yours; are you sure your xml has that 1 in it ?

Comment: Also changing that value in the config file to 2 results in "all=2"

Comment: try: $this->permissions[(string)$key] = $value;

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a million :D I'll have to remember that one!

Comment: This is weird anyway because var_dump suggests that $opt['name'] is a string but in fact it is not.  You should try a var_dump($key) it might show $key is something else.

Answer (score 0):

try to var dump like this:

```
var_dump(array_keys($this->permissions));
```

to see the structure of your array.

Comment: Thanks, I put the results in the original post.